# Derivative of squared norm of component of a matrix perpendicular to identity matrix, with respect to the original matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-calculus, trace

Let $J\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$

What is the derivative (with respect to $J$) of the squared norm of the component of $J$ that is orthogonal to $I$ (the identity matrix)?

#### Attempt

$J$'s projection onto $I$ is $\frac{\langle J,I\rangle_F}{n}I=\frac{Tr(J)}{n}I$

where $\langle A,B\rangle_F=Tr(A^TB)$ denotes the Frobenius inner product (dot product for matrices) and $Tr(A)$ denotes the trace of A.

So the orthogonal component is $J-\frac{Tr(J)}{n}I$

So we seek

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial J}||J-\frac{Tr(J)}{n}||_F^2$$
$$=\frac{\partial}{\partial J}Tr((J-\frac{Tr(J)}{n})^T(J-\frac{Tr(J)}{n}))$$
$$=\frac{\partial}{\partial J}Tr(J^TJ-\frac{Tr(J)}{n}(J^T+J)+\frac{Tr^2(J)}{n^2}I)$$

How to proceed (if correct so far)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is (relatively) easily answered using the chain rule for the [total derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_derivative). Let $f(X) = \|X\|_F^2$, and let $g(X) = X - \frac{\operatorname{tr}(X)}{n}$.  We note that $g$ is linear, so its derivative is given by $dg(X)(H) = g(H)$. On the other hand, we have
$$
f(X + H) = \operatorname{tr}[(X + H)^T(X + H)] \\
= \operatorname{tr}(X^TX)
 + 2\operatorname{tr}(X^TH) + \operatorname{tr}(H^TH)\\
= f(X) + 2\operatorname{tr}(X^TH) + o(\|H\|_F^2).
$$
Conclude that $dg(X)(H) = 2\operatorname{tr}(X^TH)$.

With the chain rule, we have
$$
d[f \circ g](X)(H) = [df(X) \circ dg(X)](H) = df(X)(g(H)) \\
= 2\operatorname{tr}(X^Tg(H)) = 2\operatorname{tr}\left(X^T[H - \frac{\operatorname{tr}(H)}{n}]\right)\\
= 2\operatorname{tr}\left(X^TH\right) - 
\frac 2n \operatorname{tr}(X)\operatorname{tr}\left(H\right).
$$
To convert this to the more conventional format of "denominator layout", we can use the [connection between notations explained here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_calculus#Identities_in_differential_form) to find that $h(J) = (f \circ g)(J)$ satisfies
$$
\frac{dh}{dJ} = 2J - \frac 2n \operatorname{tr}(J)I = 2g(J).
$$

Comment: For "numerator layout", wouldn't the result at the end be transposed since $dJ$ appears in the differential's denominator? i.e. $2g(J)^T$ ?

Comment: You're right; I meant denominator layout, good catch

Comment: @Museful Also, in reference to your deleted comment: the denominator-layout derivative indeed matches up with the "gradient", so that this derivative lines up with geometric intuition (that the direction of maximal increase is the direction of the projection).

Answer (score 3):

In continuum mechanics, they have a name for this, 

it's called the Isotropic-Deviatoric decomposition.
$$\eqalign{
{\rm iso}(A) &= \left[\frac{{\rm Tr}(A)}{{\rm Tr}(I)}\right]I,
\qquad
{\rm dev}(A) = A - {\rm iso}(A) \\
}$$
The operations are idempotent and orthogonal
$$\eqalign{
{\rm iso}({\rm iso}(A)) &= {\rm iso}(A) \\
{\rm iso}({\rm dev}(A)) &= {\rm dev}({\rm iso}(A)) \;=\; 0 \\
{\rm dev}({\rm dev}(A)) &= {\rm dev}(A) \\
}$$
and behave like the Sym-Skew operators with respect 
to the inner product
$$\eqalign{
A:B &= {\rm Tr}\big(A^TB\big) &\{\rm Frobenius\,product\}\\
0 &={\rm iso}(A):{\rm dev}(B) \\
A:{\rm iso}(B) &= {\rm iso}(A)\,:{\rm iso}(B) &= {\rm iso}(A):B \\
A:{\rm dev}(B) &= {\rm dev}(A):{\rm dev}(B) &= {\rm dev}(A):B \\
}$$
Write the current problem in terms of these operators.

Then calculate the differential and gradient.
$$\eqalign{
X &= {\rm dev}(J) \\
 \phi &= X:X \\
d\phi &= 2X:dX \\
  &= 2X:{\rm dev}(dJ) \\
  &= 2\,{\rm dev}(X):dJ \\
  &= 2X:dJ \\
\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial J} &= 2X = 2\,{\rm dev}(J) \\
}$$

Answer (score 1):

With $S(X) = \|X\|^2 = \langle X, X \rangle$ we have
$DS(X) H = 2 \langle X, H\rangle$.

Since $\phi(J)= J - {\operatorname{tr} J \over n} I$ is linear we see that $D \phi(J)H = \phi(H)$.

The chain rule gives
$D (S\circ \phi) (J)H = D S(\phi(J)) D \phi(J)H = 2 \langle \phi(J), \phi(H)\rangle$.

Unwinding (& rewinding) gives
$D (S\circ \phi) (J)H = \langle 2J - 2{\operatorname{tr} J \over n} I , H \rangle = \langle 2\phi(J), H\rangle$.